# Bash script for /dev semi-mounted volume

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a bash script to automatically mount a volume that is in /dev (EC2 EBS storage).  When the device is connected, it shows up as /dev/sdf (always)...but the "find" command does not work on it when it is there (just not technically mounted in /etc/mtab).

These do not work:

```
[ -f /dev/sdf ] && echo "It exists" || echo "It does not exist"

[ -d /dev/sdf ] && echo "It exists" || echo "It does not exist"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `-b`. See `help test`.

Comment: It's the little things in Bash that never fail to amaze me.  Thanks.